# What are the suitable methods for statistical process control with non normally distributed data such as proportion?

Tags: quality-control

Is there anyone familiar with statistical process control charts?
The usual control limits +-3SD are based on normal distribution. What are the common methods for dealing with non-normally distributed data? For example, proportions that are close to 100%.
I am not certain what kind of distribution fits. Is it OK to do log transformation?
I may not have enough sample size to do the nonparametric percentile approach.

Comment: What would you think of a quantile or percentile? // If you're not comfortable making an assumption of a normal distribution, is there some other distribution you are comfortable assuming?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Percentile would be good, but I need enormous amount of data. I only have one data point per day. It will need to accumulate for more than a year. Not sure what distribution a proportion follows. Perhaps it can be considered Poisson with an offset.

Comment: This question is really to broad for this site, as it practically is inviting for a whole book. Try to make your question more concrete and limited. But see for instance https://www.juran.com/resources/books/juran-quality-handbook-7/

Comment: You might also consult the [NIST handbook](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pmc/section5/pmc52.htm) on this specific topic. If you don't have enough data to do a useful nonparametric estimate, however, you might not have enough data to get a useful SD estimate either, even after a transformation to near-normality.